# .php?title=test to echo "test";

Tags: php, isset

I think the title says it all.

I have an URL (example: index.php?title=My title goes here) and I would like to insert the string in my page with echo.

---

[http://mywebsite.com/index.php?title=Alphanumeric title with spaces](http://mywebsite.com/index.php?title=Alphanumeric%20title%20with%20spaces) (if I can't use spaces, I will need to replace any "_" with a space in the final result)

```
The title is <b><?php echo $title; ?></b>.
```

The title is **Alphanumeric title with spaces**.

---

So, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: <?php echo $_GET['title']; ?> will display the title, you then need to run a replace function to change spaces to _

Comment: @AndyHolmes And escape `<` to prevent XSS.

Comment: `.php?title=</title><script>alert('XSS');</script>`. You might want to think about a different method instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `$_GET['title']` you can use space it will decode by `urldecode()`

```
The title is <b><?php echo (!empty($_GET['title']) ? urldecode($_GET['title']):''); ?></b>.
```

Answer (score 0):

`$title = urlencode($title);` to generate your URL Safe pagination and `urldecode($title);` for decoding it to a normal string again.

Answer (score -1):

Use $_GET[] for this
$_GET[] is an array containing all data sent through the URL

So in your case, use $_GET['title].

Also remember to use the function isset() to check if the value is actually in the URL!!!